# Multiple subplots with one dynamic super title using annotation

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I am trying to use one super title for multiple subplots. I used `annotation` to accomplish that. The `annotation` is inside a loop. The problem is the `annotation` working fine when it is not dynamic but unfortunately, I need to change title when I use `Loop`

I used below code which is working when there is no change on the title. (This is just an example of random numbers)

```
clc;
clear;
a=rand(10,10);
for i=1:3
h(1)=subplot (2,2,1);
plot (a(:,1),a(:,2));
set(h(1),'Position',[.1 .35 .35 .5])
h(2)=subplot (2,2,2);
plot (a(:,1),a(:,2));
set(h(2),'Position',[.55 .35 .35 .5])
annotation('textbox', [0 0.85 1 0.1],'String',...
 'Test text Number=1','EdgeColor', 'none','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')

end
```

I tried to change `annotation` line as below but its not working

```
annotation('textbox', [0 0.85 1 0.1],'String',...
 'Test text Number=%d',i,'EdgeColor', 'none','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
```

I do not want to use external function in my code such as (`suptitle`,`suplabel`..etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
temp=annotation('textbox', [0 0.85 1 0.1],'String',...
['Test text Number=',num2str(i)],'EdgeColor', 'none','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, the code worked correctly when I removed the last three lines. I do not understand when I need these lines.                                                                       drawnow
pause(1)
if i~=3 delete(temp); end

Comment: Removed as per your choice

Comment: 'drawnow` was helping you to visualize the plots as they were drawn with some `pause` and then `delete` was deleting the previous annotation from screen so that it won't get mixed with what was written previously!